# Can't click on href download link inside dynamically changing table using Selenium web-driver

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, hyperlink, selenium-chromedriver

I can access all of the rows I need to, and their cells. I can even access the text of the href hyperlink cell to print it. But when I try xpath or other element finding strategies to '.click', none are working. This table is in an iframe which I switch to and am able to get all the table's info (although sometimes it does complain saying no connection to page or something.)

I have tried direct xpath, // searching whole html tree xpath and others. I even tried converting all my code to watir. Anyone know without showing all my code why this nested loop gives me the row and cell I need. But won't let me click that cell? What other methods can I use than '.text' to access values of that cell to click the anchor/href that maybe isn't xpath? Thanks!

Same as above.

```
# Iterate through all cells of the table
table.find_elements(:tag_name, "tr").each do |r|
    if r.text.include? "#{Num}"   
        puts "*******************************************"
        puts "cell found in table."
        puts "*******************************************"
        puts "Row text:"
        puts r.text
        r.find_elements(:tag_name, "td").each do |c|
            puts "c.text:"
            puts c.text
            if c.text.include? "Excel"
                c = c.find_element(:xpath, "/html/body/div/table/tbody/tr[36]/td[7]/a")
                c.click
            end
        end        
    end
end
```

Just want to be able to access rows that have the text for the number entered and if that text exists anywhere in the row, go to the cell where the href is and click it.

Comment: Did you try omit the line beginning with `c =`? Are you sure condition `if c.text.include? "Excel"` is true? Try `puts c.text` inside `if`

Comment: Thanks for responding lojza! It does find it and puts the text of the td as "Excel". I just don't know how to access the span or href that is also inside the td. I have tried a third .each loop and i just can't get the find_element to get href or anchor or anything. Just always says frame detached (this is all inside an iframe but I switched to it earlier successfully and don't change pages/frames again). Or it says element doesn't exist or object type nil. I can post a picture of the html with src redacted if that helps?

Comment: Can you add to your question peace of html code where all mentioned elements are included?

Answer (score 0):

This XPath should get you all the way to the anchor tag (without all the extra work)

`"//table//tr/td[contains(text(),'#{num}')]/../td/a[contains(text(),'Excel')]"`

What it does:

- Looks for any cell in a row the contains the text of your `num` variable (`//table//tr/td[contains(text(),'#{num}')]`)
- Then selects that row (`/..`) [parent accessor]
- finds the cell with an anchor tag where the text contains the word "Excel" (`/td/a[contains(text(),'Excel')]`)

Now I don't use selenium but I am assuming that in theory the following should work:

```
table.find_element(:xpath, 
  "//tr/td[contains(text(),'#{num}')]/../td/a[contains(text(),'Excel')]").click
```

Comment: Thank you for such a comprehensive and helpful response! I've had a difficult time understanding the path of the // searches and what parents and ancestors are and how to use contains. I will try this out and let you know! Thanks :)

Comment: Do you use watir?

Comment: So I tried it and the response is one that I've been getting before -- target frame detached, what does that mean? I switched to the iframe earlier and haven't navigated away since? Thoughts?

Comment: @space_jam23 honestly not certain what that means and I primarily do backend development so I am not all that familiar with selenium or watir. Since I am not sure what your target page looks like nor how you are navigating the page this is going to be difficult to assist with